# 2 way voice as in GTalk

Tags: voip, google-voice

Can you tell me how GTalk implements 2 way voice communication?

The interaction happens without any latency even at a low bandwidth. Can we implement something like this in a website?

Can VOIP be implemented via a website without any need for a phone, with minimum 2 way voice carry delay?

Can any one please help me find some tutorials as well regarding this?

Thanks a bunch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at libjingle which Google Talk uses, they have a few examples for different platforms using voice chat.

http://code.google.com/apis/talk/libjingle/index.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the link, I will have a look at it!